# Bullet Accuracy is Off

Tags: java, algorithm, 2d

I am making a top down view tank game and I cant seem to get the bullet accuracy to be 100%
It is either just off or just on depending on my mouse position

I am using the formula below to calculate the angle to travel to reach the target (MousePosition)

```
double dx = MousePosition.x - TankPosition.x;
double dy = MousePosition.y - TankPosition.y;
double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);

double tx = Math.cos(angle) * speed;
double ty = Math.sin(angle) * speed;

x += tx;
y += ty;
```

Comment: It seems this question was closed, although I feel like the inevitable answer that was proven to be true suggests that this could be useful to others if the question was improved.  Is there any chance we can do this?

Comment: It was closed because Jack Maney and syb0rg were posting rude and unnecessary comments. I tried to edit the question. However, there is a time limit for editing posts and I wasn't within that time limit. If i get the chance again I will edit the question to be more general and not so specific. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that your problem is an integer vs. float issue, and a matter of rounding.  If you are using integers, it will round your result every tick update.  This means that depending on your mouse position, it will either be spot on (if your mouse is at a position unaffected by rounding) or slightly off, and will vary depending on said target position seemingly randomly, which sounds like your description of the problem.  You're going to want to keep track of position as a float, and round it only when using it to draw, and not when making calculations to it.